# Differences between Stream.of() and stream()

Tags: java, java-stream

I was trying to figure out where the differences between `stream.of()` and `stream()` are and I came across this. Could anyone please explain to me why the first one wouldn't work?

```
//Given: List<Integer> transactions

transactions.add(1);

transactions.add(2);

//This won't compile,

Stream.of(transactions).filter(x->x<3).collect(Collectors.toList());

// while this one does fine:

transactions.stream().filter(x->x<3).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: The error message from the compiler explains it. The javadoc, too. What does the javadoc of Stream.of() say? What does it return when you pass it a List<Integer>? And please, post the code as text, in the question. Not as a link to an image.

Comment: Please add the code you want to show in a block of code with ```code``` insted of referencing an image url

Comment: Pass them to the desired data structure in your IDE and see what the error message tells you, e.g. `List<Integer> listStreamOf = Stream.of(transactions).filter(x -> x < 3).collect(Collectors.toList());` will tell you something pretty clearly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Stream.of` creates a stream of the given parameters and `List.stream` converts your list into a stream.

Given:

```
List<Integer> myList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
```

`myList.stream()` returns a `Stream<Integer>` with content {1, 2, 3}

`Stream.of(myList)` returns a `Stream<List<Integer>>` with content { myList }